# How to disable "snap to grid" from jQuery UI draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, snap-to-grid

Anyone know how we can disable "Snap to Grid" from jQuery UI Draggable base on checkbox.

I m using below code to enable snap to grid dynamically.

```
$(".WidgetCl").draggable({containment: '#editorWindow',scroll: true, snap: ".gridCol", snapMode: "both", stop :function() {$(this).trigger("stopdrag");}})
            $(".WidgetCl").draggable("option", "grid", [ gridSize, gridSize ]);
```

Thanks,
Sonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the [grid](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-grid) option to `false` to disable snap-to-grid:

```
$(".WidgetCl").draggable("option", "grid", false);
```

Comment: Thank You.. Its working.. But it require "snap: false" also. Like $(".WidgetCl").draggable({containment: '#editorWindow',scroll: true, snap: false, snapMode: "both", stop :function() {$(this).trigger("stopdrag");}})